Fixed-point method in functional equation
Does there exists a function $f:[0,1)\cap\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow[0,1)\cap\mathbb{Q}$, such that for any $x\in[0,1)\cap\mathbb{Q}$, $f(f(x))=\{nx\}$, where $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, and $\{x\}=x-[x]$? What if the domain range becomes $[0,1)$, and $x\in[0,1)$?
It is clear to see that for any $n=k^2$, where $k\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, we let $f(x)=\{kx\}$, then $f(f(x))=\{k\{kx\}\}=\{k\cdot kx-k\cdot[kx]\}=\{nx\}$, which satisfies both the condition.
As an example of $n\ne k^2$, we let $n=2$, we noticed that $f(f(\frac{1}{3}))=\frac{2}{3}$ and $f(f(\frac{2}{3}))=\frac{1}{3}$, which means $\frac{1}{3}$ and $\frac{2}{3}$ are fixed point of degree $4$. The conditon means we can also find another pair of fixed point of degree $4$, but that is contradictory under simple analysis. We guessed the same method can be used in other cases.

Are you sure about the $x \in [0, 1) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ restriction? If so, $$f(x) = \begin{cases} x+1 & \text{for } x \in [0, 1) \cap \mathbb{Q}, \ { n(x-1) } &\text{for } x \in [1, 2) \cap \mathbb{Q}, \ \text{whatever} & \text{elsewhere} \end{cases}$$ works.

Maybe there's some misunderstanding... When I use $x\in [0,1)\cap\mathbb{Q}$, I try to imply that $x$ values on all the rational numbers in between $[0,1)$. So is it ok to write so?

Yes, the restriction $x \in [0, 1) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ means that $x$ ranges over the rational numbers in the interval $[0, 1)$. But in this case the example above is a valid answer to the question. Maybe you wanted the values of $f$ to also range over the rationals in $[0, 1)$? In this case $f : \mathbb{Q} \cap [0, 1) \to \mathbb{Q} \cap [0, 1)$ is the way to indicate that.
